# Different web.configs for one solution depending on which site request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, iis, config

In my web application I want two different authentication modes. 
*Windows* and *Forms*.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

For irrelevant reasons I need to set up two different sites in IIS.
One site is using Windows Authentication the other one Forms.
I want the sites to be mapped to the same project.
The only difference should be the web.config file, simply put one line:

Web.config 1

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

Web.config 2

```
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

An easy solution would be to simple have two sites mapped to two identical projects, containing different configs. Although, this could cause problems/difficulties in the future regarding maintenance, since one has to remember to publish new changes to both of the projects.

"*If a client tries to enter site 1 with url XXX they should be prompted the Windows Autentication (configured in browser to support SSO). If a client tries to enter site 2 with url yyy they should be prompted to enter credentials for a SQL user in a form login.*"

**Is it somehow possible to achieve my desire without having two identical projects?**

Answer (score 1):

Use configurations and config transforms. By default, your site comes with two configurations: Debug and Release. However, you can add as many as you like. For example, you can add configurations like "Site1" and "Site2" (Build > Configuration Manager...). Then, right-click your Web.config file and choose "Add Config Transform". If you expand the `Web.config` item, you'll now see `Web.Site1.config` and `Web.Site2.config`. These are your transforms. Using the [config transform syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx), you can customize the `<authentication>` tags for each. Then, when you publish your site, just choose the right configuration for the version of the site you're publishing.

Comment: You lost me at the last sentence. If I have to choose the right configuration when publishing that only, let's say I choose "Web.Site1.config" then the published solution will only contain the config from that one? Not both. Or am I missing something?

Comment: When you publish, you have to select a configuration. Typically, that's one of Debug or Release. However, if you add additional configurations, then you can pick from those as well, i.e. Site1 and Site2 in this example. When you pick a configuration, that config transform is applied to the actual Web.config and then the transformed Web.config is published.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I think you are misunderstanding what I want. What you are suggesting is an easy way to swap between developing and live site settings. What I want is the two different configurations available on publishing at the same time. Simply put: If a client enters the website on his windows machine then it will automatically use the settings in site1.config, otherwise they will be using the site2.config.

Comment: That's not possible. The Web.config is *application*-based, not user-based. You can't switch it out per user, as that would require the entire web application to restart. The best you can do is publish two different sites. If you set things up right, you can even have a domain route to one server internally and another externally, so if a user comes in on the intranet, they'll get the Windows Auth version. That's the best you can do though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no overlap, you can use the location tag within the web.config:

```
  <location path="Some/Path">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms" />
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Another/Path">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Windows" />
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Where the paths are your url XXX and YYY.

Comment: What do you mean by "assuming no overlap"? I tried this approach. But get an error which says "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level".

Comment: If the paths XXX and YYY are completely independent.

Comment: Yes they are completely independent.